# How Django view's decide which html page to render/display?

Tags: django, django-views

In my View i have not mentions template_name then how django will decide which html page to render during request?

Here is my views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render


from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from . models import Movie

class MovieList(ListView):
    model = Movie

   # template_name = 'movie_list.html'
class MovieDetail(DetailView):
    model = Movie
    #template_name = 'movie_detail.html'
```

As shown in code i haven't mention any template_name then how django know page location?

when i use url "http://localhost:8000/movies/" it display's MovieList.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render


from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from . models import Movie

class MovieList(ListView):
    model = Movie

   # template_name = 'movie_list.html'
class MovieDetail(DetailView):
    model = Movie
    #template_name = 'movie_detail.html'
```

Taking your example -

Example: if model name is `Movie`

- for `ListView`:  `movie_list.html`
- for `DetailView`: `movie_detail.html`
- for `DeleteView`: `movie_confirm_delete.html`
- for `CreateView` & `UpdateView`: `movie_form.html`

As you can see it takes the model name  in lowercase and adds the view type after the underscore. You can experiment it by  running the application without the templates and then it will raise the `DoesNotExist` error saying it couldn't find `movie_list.html` if you haven't made it already in template folder. For all CBV's you'll see the name of html django wants.

Comment: For CreateView it will be movie_create right? and if it generate by default then when we use template_name ?

Comment: @gaurav Yes, definitely

Comment: @gaurav Also please accept the answer for future references.

Answer (score 1):

By default Django generate `template_name` using your model name and some [suffix/prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects).

For instance, for a `ListView`, the `template_name` is generated in the [MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/views/generic/list.py#L161) object. In your case:

- `MovieList`: `movie_list.html`
- `MovieDetail`: `movie_detail.html`